# MySQL syntax error when inputting file path into table using python mysql.connector

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-python

I'm trying to take an input from the user in the form of a file path and then insert it into a table using string injection but I keep getting the error

```
mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1064 (42000): You have 
an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds 
to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use 
near '/home/pi/Music/Ballads1)' at line 1
```

This is my python code

```
import mysql.connector
import serial

def read_rfid ():
   ser = serial.Serial ("/dev/ttyS0")                           #Open named port
   ser.baudrate = 9600                                            #Set baud rate to 9600
   data = ser.read(12)                                            #Read 12 characters from serial port to data
   ser.close ()                                                   #Close port
   data=data.decode("utf-8")
   return data

mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
        host = 'localhost',
        user = 'pi',
        password = '*********',
        database = 'music_to_card'
)

cursor = mydb.cursor()

tF = 1
while tF == 1:
    print('Place card over reader')

    cardNumber = read_rfid()

    print('Enter Path to folder')

    path = input()
    
    cursor.execute(f'INSERT INTO music(cardNumber,path) VALUES ({cardNumber},{path})')
    
    print('Inserted into database. Would you like to enter another? y/n')

    yN = input()

    if yN == y:
        tF = 0
print('End')
```

I'm not sure if the error is in my SQL syntax or my Python syntax hut I'm pretty sure that both are correct so if there's something I'm missing then any help is greatly appreciated.

Edit: Both cardNumber and path are varchar(255)

Comment: `path` is a string, so it should be enclosed in quotes.

Comment: Better use prepared statement